MySQL Partition table based on two columns
I have an events table which holds historical data of 10 year's with daily coming new data. Now the total rows in this table are 22560041.
Table has column's id, title, status (1-4), start_date and I want to divide it into 6 partitions- first 4 partition based on status like p0 holds records where status is 1 and p1 hold records where status = 2 and so on but for partition 5 & 6 I want to use start_date column to check with now() function like if start_date less than now() then it should come in p4 and if start_date > now() then It should come under p5.
I tried partition by RANGE with 2 columns but that works with OR condition and also not supports the date functions.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

You must combine all your conditions to ONE value and use it for partitioning. But your conditions are wrong - you want to put one row to 2 partitions which is not possible. Also you cannot use non-deterministic function (NOW) in the partitioning expression.

Looking at "historical data of 10 year's with daily coming new data. Now the total rows in this table are 22560041" I think that partitioning by the year will be enough... if the partitioning is reasonable at all in your case. I think that proper indexing may be more effective.

Hi @user:10138734,
Thanks for your thoughts but we have need where we mostly work on status base so we need partitioning on status base and then we have one scenario where we have to check records based on start date doesn't matter which status they're on.

Two indices which matches your scenarios, by status and by start date, must be enough.

Generally, Partitioning is useles for query optimization; see https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint ,  For further discussion, please provide the SELECT and SHOW CREATE TABLE.
